# EMV on chip application

Tags: emv

Who writes on chip EMV application that communicates with terminal?
Are those developed by entities like VISA, Mastercard and given to issuing bank or the card issuing bank develops it and loads onto chip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most simple terms,

Card manufacturers manufacture card and also installs operating system and applet ( if java - open platform).

Card issuers personalize these cards( I guess you know what will be there in an emv card).

After personalization, card is ready to use.

Comment: As per your response, when the card comes out from manufacturing facility, it is ready for personalization step.
So basically the underlying application is the same, during personalization we assign AIDs and other parameters to the application, from there onwards it gets adentified as a visa,mastercard,amex.. application, am I correct?

Comment: Yes. It is ready for personalization. The underlying application can be different, C/Java based, but for the terminal, it is transparent whether the card runs on Multos / Global platform as the communication is via interoperable APDUs.  Yes it is based on the AIDs it gets identified as to which application it contains.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who wrote EMV application (either native or javacard applet) and pass the payment scheme certification (functional or security), he could sell his product.

The general idea is that the application developed have to pass the mandated certification test before going to the market and carrying the payment scheme brand.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specification (ISO/IEC 7816-4) which specifies the protocol of an EMV card. It is on the net. Just google emvco and you would find them. The specification is complicated and takes time to understand. Here is a youtube channel
 https://youtu.be/iWg8EBhsfjY
 explaining the specification in a simple way. Especially for beginner. Check it out if you are interested.